# Bubble sort on an already sorted collection

Tags: algorithms, sorting

When I look at the following algorithm, I believe I understand how bubble sort works.

```
procedure bubblesort
    for i := 1 to n − 1
        for j := 1 to n − i
            if a[j] > a[j+1]
            then
                interchange a[j] and a[j+1]
            endif
        endfor
    endfor
endprocedure
```

However I am having a little tough time understanding statements like the following:

> The only significant advantage that bubble sort has over most other
> algorithms, even quicksort, but not insertion sort, is that the
> ability to detect that the list is sorted efficiently is built into
> the algorithm.

I see bubble sort having to make `n-1` passes, no matter what the sorted status of the collection is.  Obviously I am missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably that statement does not come from the same source where you got the pseudocode from. Another common way to define Bubblesort is the following:

```
procedure bubblesort
    sorted := false
    while not sorted
        sorted := true
        for j := 1 to n − i
            if a[j] > a[j+1] then
                swap a[j] and a[j+1]
                sorted := false
            endif
        endfor
    endwhile
endprocedure
```

As you can see there will be only one iteration of the outer loop when the collection is already sorted.